# DurandalJS - Widget is not reinitialized on subsequent requests

Tags: durandal

**This is an example of the problem: widget is not reinitialized on subsequent requests**

I have a "pager" widget. The first time I navigate to a page where it is used, *ctor* is executed and the pager is initialized (page 1).

Now let say I navigate to page 6.

The problem is when I navigate to another page and then back to the page where the pager is, the pager (widget) is still rendered with page 6 selected and *ctor* is not executed. **The widget controller is not a singleton.**

Is there something I don't get?

Comment: Can you post the javascript code for your widget?

Comment: I do have the same problem.

Comment: I am using a single widget three time in the same page but some of the data is shared between the 3 instance. i some how seams to be a single instance in 3 places... I need it to be 3 separate instances.

Answer (score 0):

Since the page is not re-rendered (so the widget), none of the  widget's life cycle callbacks will be called. What you can do though it to communicate with widget from parent page's activate method by

1. Raise an event from root page's activate method which widget
   listens
2. Update data in some observable which widget subscribes to
3. Or, dirty way - don't do it, just re render the widget by
       wrapping widget with with/if  binding which would change for each
       activate method call. This may be helpful if you cannt change the
       widget code, which is very unlikely.